# Whats the learning curve for Lustre/Scade

Tags: real-time

I gotta take a seminar this year in my graduate level course which later will get converted into a two year project.

I am a developer with extensive experience in Java, Ruby, PHP, Python etc. I was wondering if Lustre and Scade which are used in Realtime environments would make sense to me.

If there is anyone here with experience in these languages please tell me about the learning curve of these new languages.

Answer (score 1):

Lustre/Scade are used to program reactive systems. They solve different problems so you can not really compare them to Java, Ruby...

I found Lustre very easy to pick up. It has a only a small number of orthogonal concepts, that can be assembled together to create sophisticated behaviors (for a reactive system :) ). The "substitution principle" give you an easy way to predict what a program will do.

Of course, you can observe/create behaviors that contradict the mathematical view of Lustre programs as equations over infinite streams, but presumably you will not interface with C in a Lustre beginner course.